# Move files between azure file share and blob

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files, azure-files

I have to move some files between a share and a blob on the same storage account.
After some googleing I ended up with this code:

```
CloudFileClient fileClient = account.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("shareName");
CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
CloudFileDirectory videoDirectory = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(video.StoragePath);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(video.StoragePath);
container.CreateIfNotExists();

foreach (var Files in videoDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories())
{
    var arr = Files.Uri.ToString().Split('/');
    string strFileName = arr[arr.Length - 1];
    CloudFile sourceFile = videoDirectory.GetFileReference(strFileName);
    string fileSas = sourceFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
    });

    Uri fileSasUri = new Uri(sourceFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + fileSas);

    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(strFileName);
    blockBlob.StartCopyAsync(fileSasUri).Wait();    //copy the file to blob storage and wait for the operation to complete
    //sourceFile.DeleteAsync();    //delete the file  
}
//videoDirectory.DeleteAsync();    //delete the directory
```

If the delete lines are uncommented the destination contains all the files in the source folder but with 0 in size.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

I also want to delete the share directory after all the files are copied. Is there a way to check if the files are in the destination folder?

Comment: StartCopy() is asynchrous, its completion doesn't means the copy process has finished. You need to check the copy state in destination blob after that.

Comment: According to another answer on stackoverflow (I cannot find now), I could do StartCopy() and Delete() one after the other and the operations will run synchronously on the same account. I also tried that and the files had 0 in size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the cloud blob StartCopyAsync method means you tell the server side start to copy blob form the file storage.

But it will not wait the copy operation execute completely.

So if you want to delete the file after the file has already executed  completely, you should use FetchAttributes method to get the blob’s status.

If the status is complete, you could delete the file.

More details, you could refer to follow codes:

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
"connection string");
        CloudFileClient fileClient = account.CreateCloudFileClient();

        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("sharetest");

        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

        CloudFileDirectory videoDirectory = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("TestDirectory");

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("testdirectory");

        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        foreach (var Files in videoDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories())
        {
            var arr = Files.Uri.ToString().Split('/');
            string strFileName = arr[arr.Length - 1];
            CloudFile sourceFile = videoDirectory.GetFileReference(strFileName);
            string fileSas = sourceFile.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessFilePolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessFilePermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
            });

            Uri fileSasUri = new Uri(sourceFile.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString() + fileSas);

            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(strFileName);

            blockBlob.StartCopyAsync(fileSasUri).Wait();
            blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
            while (blockBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(50);
                blockBlob.FetchAttributes();
            }

            if (blockBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Success)
            {
                sourceFile.DeleteAsync();
            }
```